# how to show a value from a database in an input field in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I liked to know how I can show a value from my database into an input field. I'm working with CakePHP.

Right now, I have some empty fields, but I want them filled with the database values when I display my page the first time and of course when there are values in the database relative to these fields. I'm able to retrieve all my database data, but unable to show them into the fields.

Is there an easy way with CakePHP to do it or I need to set each field individually in my controller and retrieve it in my view.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to fill forms from the controller, by using $this->form->data.

Example:

```
$this->request->data = $this->YourModel->findById($id);
```

Edit:

You have to create your form with the form helpers to attach the form to your model, otherwise it won't work.

```
echo $this->Form->create('YourModel');
```